# Get loopback models using loopback-datasource-juggler

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Is there any other way other than getting the loopback model by using app object in a custom js file?

Found that requiring server.js file is possible.

```
var app = require('/server/server');
```

But the problem is that each time when we are using app object, its restarting, since each time server is getting started.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it this way, for example in boot scripts you have a custom file and you can pass the app object as:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.models.User.find({}, (err, users) => {
    console.log('USERS:', users);
  });
};
```

Or where do you put your custom js file and how do you include it?

Comment: Actually I need to create a seperate custom.js file not bootscript.

Comment: So you want to use just models by a different app? I don't know what are the requirements, but wouldn't be better to provide an endpoint that will do on loopback side what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should look like this:

**customer.js**

```js
module.exports = function (Customer) {
  let app
  
  // Use app in your remote methods or hooks
  
  Customer.on('attached', function (a) {
    app = a
  })
}
```